# How do I make var_dump apear in separate lines?

Tags: php

I don't want to know about other options then var_dump, because this is for a homework assignment and my teacher wants to me to make a var_dump and then let the different object appear in separate lines, I searched a shitload of sites and I simply cant find anything pls help.

This i the code in "verzenden.php"

```
echo '<pre>' . var_dump($_GET) . '</pre>' . '<br>';
```

*pre was standing in <> and "" but it wont show up in here*

I tried this but it is still the same as var_dump

```
<form method='get' action='verzend.php'>
    <label>Naam: </label><input name='naam' type='text' value=''>
    <label>Klas: </label><input name='klas' type='text' value=''>
    <label>Nummer: </label><input name='leerlingnummer' type='text' value=''>
    <label>Vak: </label><select name='vak'>
        <option value='PHP'>PHP</option>
        <option value='javascript'>Javascript</option>
        <option value='ASP'>ASP</option>
        <option value='SQL'>SQL</option>
    </select>
    <label>Cijfer: </label><input name='cijfer' type='number' value='5'>
    <input type='submit' value='verzend' name='verzend'>
</form>
```

this is what it needs to become

```
array(6) { ["naam"]=> string(9) "Abu Saebu" 
    ["Klas"]=> string(5) "IO1A4" 
    ["leerlingnummer"]=> string(8) "36353535" 
    ["vak"]=> string(3) "PHP" 
    ["cijfer"]=> string(1) "9" 
    ["verzend"]=> string(7) "verzend" 
}
```

This is what I get

```
array(6) { ["naam"]=> string(6) "Sjoerd" ["klas"]=> string(5) "IO1D4" ["leerlingnummer"]=> string(6) "332309" ["vak"]=> string(10) "javascript" ["cijfer"]=> string(2) "24" ["verzend"]=> string(7) "verzend" }
```

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried

Comment: echo '<pre>' . var_dump($_GET) . '</pre>' . '<br>';

Comment: This is what i have tried but nothing happens

Comment: What is `var_dump($_GET)` returning? Like what is there multiple of that needs to be on separate lines? Sounds like you need a loop that iterates a new line `\n`

Comment: You say nothing happens -- are you passing data in your URL? Is there actually something in `$_GET` to output?

Comment: @alanlittle Even if the $_GET is empty, it'll var_dump an empty array.

Comment: If i try to upload the code the site says its wrong (me thinkg no shit thats why I ask help)

Comment: @ChinLeung True. Gizoopy: From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php): "As with anything that outputs its result directly to the browser, the output-control functions can be used to capture the output of this function, and save it in a string (for example)." `var_dump` does not return its output, thus you cannot `echo` it.

Comment: `verzend.php`  page code? paste it also

Comment: so you are getting everything then what is the problem?

Comment: I need to get it in separate lines (see the main tread for the example)

Comment: Thanks for the fast feed back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two line instead of a concatenate.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_GET);
```

This will give you the following:

```
array(6) {
  ["naam"]=>
  string(9) "Abu Saebu"
  ["Klas"]=>
  string(5) "I01A4"
  ["leerlingnummer"]=>
  string(8) "36353535"
  ["vak"]=>
  string(3) "PHP"
  ["cijfer"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["verzend"]=>
  string(7) "verzend"
}
```

If you don't want it to break after the `=>`, you could use the `print_r` instead:

```
Array
(
    [naam] => Abu Saebu
    [Klas] => I01A4
    [leerlingnummer] => 36353535
    [vak] => PHP
    [cijfer] => 9
    [verzend] => verzend
)
```

However, if you really want to use `var_dump`, there's a cool extension out there named [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) that will dump the details in one line like this without the `pre` tag:

```
array (size=6)
  'naam' => string 'Abu Saebu' (length=9)
  'Klas' => string 'I01A4' (length=5)
  'leerlingnummer' => string '36353535' (length=8)
  'vak' => string 'PHP' (length=3)
  'cijfer' => string '9' (length=1)
  'verzend' => string 'verzend' (length=7)
```

More information about the pre tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: It breaks after => and that is not what the assignment said but if this isn't possible to fix then is this good enough for me

Comment: sorry if I am not totally clear about this, this is my first thread and so I don't know what you all need to know

Comment: Thanks for the fast feed back

Comment: @Gizoopy No worries! Take a look at my update if you still want to `var_dump` in one line.